# Avoiding multiple cron jobs when logged into multiple terminals

Tags: unix, cron, redundancy

I am trying to setup **cron** in a **Unix** environment to sync my code and config files to a backup folder every hour.

I need this to happen whenever I'm logged into my work terminal and at an hourly frequency. So, I inserted the following into my .bashrc file:

```
0 * * * * rsync -avz ~/codes/ /cheap/code_bkp
```

However, now when I'm logged into multiple work terminals, each of them run the job independently and I get multiple emails(1 for each terminal) every hour.

I would like to ensure **only 1 terminal** runs the cron job. Kindly suggest some way of doing so and avoiding the multiple terminal issue.

Comment: It's not clear from your question how you're currently recognising that the terminal is logged in - you mention .bashrc, but your only listing is from a crontab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is something along the lines of a reference count: if you put this in .bashrc

`( counter=$(cat ~/.login_count); echo $(( $counter + 1 )) > ~/.login_count )`

and something like this in .bash_logout

`( counter=$(cat ~/.login_count); echo $(( $counter - 1 )) > ~/.login_count )`

Then `~/.login_count` will contain the number of active terminal sessions, assuming you always log out cleanly.

You can then test that this is non-zero in your cronjob to see if at least one terminal is logged in:

`0 * * * * [ $(cat ~/tmp/counter) > 0 ] && do_backup`